# Java NON Blocking IO Rest services

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, nio, nonblocking

I'm studying reactive programming and I've a doubt about it's the implementation for Java REST web services of Non Blocking IO.
The Java **Servlet 3.1** specification introduced some interfaces in order to implement NON-blocking web requests.

My question about it are:

1. does **Netty** implement this specification and Tomcat, JBoss, Jetty **not**?
2. how to make HTTP non blocking calls from a front-end in Javascript? Can I use only AJAX, or do I have to use **AJAX+Promise** in Javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: The term "non-blocking" can mean different things to different people. On the server side you might be talking about non-blocking IO, which is used by all decent application servers to improve low level networking performance.

Comment: Thanks for the precisation. I've just modified the title and some part of the question in order to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

To answer a part of the the second part, JavaScript is inherently non-blocking. So Ajax by itself is non-blocking, and so is its Promise form.

Here is an introduction to Ajax which discusses a number of approaches including the `fetch` API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Here is the jQuery `get` API, which as it notes is a shorthand or wrapper over AJAX: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/